# Converting a list of lists to a single database

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and trying to figure out how to convert a list of lists to a single database. The list of lists is generated from parallel processing of a model I developed in a separate platform called NetLogo. The extension RNetLogo allows for the two to communicate. The code I'm using to parallelize a function is:

```
sim <- function(y){
  results=list()
  NLCommand("setup")
  ret <- NLDoReport(48,"go", "count breeding-males + count breeding-females", as.data.frame=TRUE, df.col.names=c("breeding.animals"));
  ret1 <-NLReport("mean male-land-tenure-list")
  names(ret1) <- c("male.land.tenure")
  results[[1]]=ret
  results[[2]]=ret1
  return(results)
}
repetitions <- 1:16
clusterExport(cl, 'sim')
results.test <-parSapply(cl, repetitions, function(y){sim()})
print(data.frame(results.test))
```

The output `results.test` has all the results I need. A sample of `results.test` looks like:

```
X1
1 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 61, 63, 66, 66, 66, 67
2 
27.4
X2
1 ...
```

The structure `str` of the data is:

```
List of 32
 $ :List of 48 
 $ : num 27.4
...
```

`X1`, `X2`, `X3`... are the run numbers. Two lists (`ret` and `ret1`) are associated with each run. 
But I'd like to combine all of them like below, with the first column being the run number. In this case, it would be 1 - 16. The next column would be time.step, which in this case goes from 1- 48. Finally, the 48 length `ret` would be "breeding.adults". Ideally I'd like to have the output `ret1` (male.land.tenure) be kept in a separate dataframe that shows which run number it belonged to. Basically, any suggestions on how to get the data out of lists and into a usable dataframe would be hugely appreciated.

```
run.number  time.step   breeding.adults
1   0   58
2   0   58
1   1   58
4   0   58
3   0   58
2   1   58
4   1   58
3   1   58
1   2   58
2   2   58
4   2   58
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but maybe something like `cbind(run.number=rep(1:length(results.test), each=48), time.step=rep(1:48, length(results.test)), breeding.adults=sapply(results.test, '[[', 1))`

Comment: Yeah! That was very close. The length was 32 instead of 16, but I modified it slightly to `cbind(run.number=rep(1:length(results.test[1,]),each=48), time.step=rep(1:48, length(results.test[1,])), breeding.adults=sapply(results.test[1,],'[[', 1))`. Then added another line to grab the `male.land.tenure` with `cbind(run.number=rep(1:length(results.test[2,])), male.land.tenure=sapply(results.test[2,],'[[', 1))`. Seemed to work like a charm!

Comment: @jbaums I upvoted your comment because it was right, but I'm not sure how to designate this question as answered without answering it myself.

Comment: No worries - I would have been happy for you to answer it yourself, but was already midway through converting it to an answer. I didn't  really understand where `male.land.tenure` came into it, since it wasn't shown in your example output. Glad you worked it out, anyway

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that generates both desired `data.frame`s (as `data.table`s) directly.

You'll need "reshape2" for the `melt` function (for which we are using the `list` method) and my "splitstackshape" package for the `getanID` function.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(reshape2)
```

From there, it's a simple `lapply` across the sequence of 1:2, since we know we want the first sublist item as one `data.frame` and the second sublist item as another `data.frame`:

```
lapply(1:2, function(x) getanID(melt(lapply(L, "[[", x)), "L1"))
# [[1]]
#     value L1 .id
#  1:     3  1   1
#  2:     4  1   2
#  3:     5  1   3
#  4:     7  1   4
#  5:     2  1   5
#  6:     8  1   6
#  7:     9  1   7
#  8:     6  1   8
#  9:    10  1   9
# 10:     1  1  10
# 11:     3  2   1
# 12:    10  2   2
# 13:     5  2   3
# 14:    14  2   4
# 15:     6  2   5
# 16:     8  2   6
# 17:     9  2   7
# 18:     4  2   8
# 19:    11  2   9
# 20:     7  2  10
# 21:     2  2  11
# 22:    15  2  12
# 23:     1  2  13
# 24:    12  2  14
# 25:    13  2  15
#     value L1 .id
# 
# [[2]]
#         value L1
# 1: 0.20597457  1
# 2: 0.01339033  2
```

The only real prerequisite knowledge required here is that when you `melt` a list, the values come in one column (named "value"), and other columns are created in the naming pattern of "L1", "L2" and so on for nested lists. Since we aren't dealing with any nesting, we know we will just have an "L1" that we can use to generate our ID.

---

This answer uses `L` from @jbaums's answer, with `set.seed(1)`, as the sample data.

Comment: This is really slick! If my data.tables have the same length of `L1` and `.id`, is it possible to combine the `value` fields from the data.tables into a single data.frame with, for example, `L1`, `.id`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the list elements represent individual runs, 1 through `length(results.test)`, and the first element of each of the elements of `results.test` holds the number of breeding adults across time steps.

To bind these together into a single dataframe, you could use:

```
# Create an example list with equivalent structure
L <- list(list(sample(10), runif(1)), list(sample(15), runif(1)))

# Simplify the list to just the breeding adults elements
breeding_adults <- lapply(L, '[[', 1)

# Bind together the relevant information
cbind(run=unlist(mapply(rep, seq_along(breeding_adults), 
                        each=sapply(breeding_adults, length))),
      timestep=unlist(sapply(breeding_adults, seq_along)),
      n=unlist(breeding_adults))

#       run timestep  n
#  [1,]   1        1 10
#  [2,]   1        2  3
#  [3,]   1        3  6
#  [4,]   1        4  7
#  [5,]   1        5  4
#  [6,]   1        6  8
#  [7,]   1        7  9
#  [8,]   1        8  1
#  [9,]   1        9  2
# [10,]   1       10  5
# [11,]   2        1  5
# [12,]   2        2 12
# [13,]   2        3  3
# [14,]   2        4  6
# [15,]   2        5  2
# [16,]   2        6 10
# [17,]   2        7 13
# [18,]   2        8  9
# [19,]   2        9  8
# [20,]   2       10 14
# [21,]   2       11 15
# [22,]   2       12 11
# [23,]   2       13  4
# [24,]   2       14  1
# [25,]   2       15  7
```

Comment: cbind here produced data of `List of 2 $ : int [1:10] 1 6 3 5 4 10 7 9 2 8 $ : int [1:15] 10 15 2 12 8 11 6 9 4 1 ...` My data looks like: `List of 16 $ : num [1:100] 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 ... $ : num [1:100] 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 ...` I get the following error with the cbind: `In cbind(run = unlist(mapply(rep, seq_along(breeding_adults), each = sapply(breeding_adults, : number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 3)` Any thoughts on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I generated a sample data set to play with this problem:

```
a <- list(list(as.list(1:4),5),list(as.list(11:14),6))
```

Code to reformat `ret`:

```
rets <- lapply(a,`[[`,1)
names(rets) <- paste0(seq_along(rets),'_')
un <- unlist(rets)
d <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(names(un),'_')),breeding.adults=un)
colnames(d)[1:2] <- c('run.number',  'time.step')
```

Code to reformat `ret1`:

```
rets1 <- lapply(a,`[[`,2)
data.frame(run.number=seq_along(rets1),male.land.tenure=unlist(rets1))
```

I hope this solution will work for your data set as well.